# Streamlines for the velocity field $(x, y, 0)$?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

Using the equation

$$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{y}$$
the streamlines for the velocity field $u = (x, y, 0)$ are given by $x = By$ where $B$ is some arbitrary constant.

This will give us infinitely many streamlines that all go through the origin. But I thought streamlines couldn't cross each other?

Streamlines are tangents to the function $u$ at any particular time $t$. So we are getting infinitely many tangents at the origin?

Furthermore, the equation $\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy} {y}$ seems problematic as $x$ and $y$ can be $0$.

So there is a problem at the origin. Can someone tell me what is the correct interpretation of the streamlines for the velocity field $(x, y, 0)$?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in this case the origin presents an unstable equilibrium point, in the sense that if you put a test particle exactly at the origin, and there is no noise/fluctuation, it will stay there, but if there is even a tiniest fluctuation it will drift off origin. The reason is that $u=(0,0)$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Put it another way, the equations of motion for a test particle are:
$$ dx=x dt \\
dy = y dt$$
therefore if the starting point is $(x,y)=(0,0)$, theoretically a test body will not move as $dx=dy=0$. This explains the singularity at the origin.

The streamlines crossing each other also arises from the same singularity above.

Comment: So streamlines can cross each other? I ask because there are countless sources out there where I have read that streamlines can't cross each other.

Comment: Imagine two sheets of glass parallel to one another, creating a very thin 2D cavity sheet over the x-y plane. Now imagine a (perpendicular) needle at the origin, constantly injecting a fluid. The fluid will flow radially outward from the origin, therefore, provided the diameter of the needle is infinitesimal, the flow lines will all originate from it (the origin) and therefore all cross. Does that paint a clear picture?

Comment: Lots of books and websites say that the streamlines can't cross. The first paragraph here for example - http://books.google.ie/books?id=ybEIAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA299&lpg=PA299&dq=%22streamlines+can%27t+cross%22&source=bl&ots=RDvBNvWW6C&sig=a4rpofr3E9x1aiYkKEXHZrOyTR8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_oJsVMygFcyeNrKbgdAE&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22streamlines%20can't%20cross%22&f=false

Comment: I could not open the link you posted, it says access restricted. But see [here](https://www.princeton.edu/~asmits/Bicycle_web/streamline.html): "Since the velocity at any point in the flow has a single value (the flow cannot go in more than one direction at the same time), streamlines cannot cross. except at points where the velocity magnitude is zero, such as at a stagnation point."